# As a SharePoint Guest, is there a way to attach files in the Outlook app for Windows using the "Browse Web Locations" feature?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, sharepoint, attachments, guest

I work in IT and am helping a SharePoint guest who works closely with another tenant, attach files to her Outlook client straight from that tenant's SharePoint. Is there way to make this work through "Browse Web Locations?"

Currently she is downloading all the documents. Note that B2B sync isn't available in this case so she can't attach straight from syncing in File Explorer either.
Appreciate any ideas thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook, go to File > Office Account, click the "Add a service" option，choose "OneDrive for Business", enter the account of the SharePoint guest,
[image]

If the SharePoint site can be added together with the OneDrive for Business, then you can access the SharePoint site through "Browser Web locations":
[image]

If this doesn't work, you can consider syncing the SharePoint files to your computer for easier access in Outlook.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. It doesn't work, you can't access any guest storage this way. Only your main tenant's.

Comment: Okay. I am not aware of any 3rd-party plugin or utilities for this requirement, and if you cannot find any either, probably syncing the files locally in advance could be the better way.
Meanwhile, you can open an item in the MS feedback portal through https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/. This can make it an official request to Outlook Engineering and others can vote on the feature as well.

Comment: This request is too niche for the feedback portal to be effective. Anyway I think I found a good third party solution - it's called One place solutions. https://help.oneplacesolutions.com/gettingstarted/getting-started.htm 
   https://youtu.be/lFC6yFSNW9E

Comment: Great! Thanks for the share!

Comment: Thanks but I think I jumped to conclusions in my excitement. Not sure the software works for guests. I'm going to reach out to the vendor and update here.